How to use @Retry on Quarkus
I have a void method and I put @Retry on it.
    @Retry(jitter = 0, delay = 1, delayUnit = HOURS, maxDuration = 4, durationUnit = HOURS)
    @Blocking
    public void myMethod(final String value) {
        //blocking code
    }

and when I launch my application with Quarkus in dev mode I have this error:
Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 60352 ms, time limit is 60000 ms: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
        at java.base@17.0.10/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.retry.ThreadSleepDelay.sleep(ThreadSleepDelay.java:19)
        at io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.retry.Retry.doApply(Retry.java:59)

Why and how to fix that?
I'm using Quarkus 3.8.5

How did you write your blocking code ? With Mutiny ? Because Mutiny doesn’t support @Retry annotation. You have to do it programmatically in Mutiny.

No we use imperative mode. Not use Mutiny. I have the impression that @Retry block a worker thread 3 hours in my case. I use this quarkus.vertx.max-worker-execute-time=4h and it's seems to work. But It's strange that it block thread between each retry

Why did you add @Blocking then ? Can you remove that and see whether it works ?

It is impossible for retry to not block between attempts in this case, where everything is synchronous. (It's not apparent because this method returns void, but what if it returned a String?) If your method returns a CompletionStage<...> (and since you're not using nonblocking programming, the method should likely be annotated @Asynchronous as well), there will be no thread blocking.

Ok I test with @Asynchronous annotation and returning a CompletionStage, it's work. But I don't understand why because my code is always blocking because I just return Future.succeededFuture("pop").toCompletionStage() . Is it good? The thread is a executor-thread-1 on the top of this method there is a Scheduler
